# colored coefficients using package chemformula

Tags: chemformula

For a beamer presentation I want to apply the nice chemformula package. I now wish to have only the coefficients colored individually, for example marking the first coefficient in blue:

```
\ch{\color{blue}106 CO2 + 122 H2O + 16 HNO3 + H3PO4 -> (CH2O)106 + (NH3)16(H3PO4) + 138 O2}
```

As soon as I include the \color command (as explained in the chemformula manual), the coefficient becomes a subscript.
I also tried

```
\ch{ \textcolor{blue}{106} CO2 + 122 H2O + ...,
```

which generates the same result. The equation looks fine when I omit any attempt coloring the coefficients. What am I missing here? I assume that there is a very simple solution to this problem. Any advice is much appreciated, thanks. Markus

Answer (score 4):

A stoichiometric factor may only contain  numbers and the signs `. ,_ /()`.

As alternative you might  prevent `chemformula` from parsing the input, for example using
`\ch{"⟨escaped text⟩"}`

Compounds are more straightforward. (Third formula)

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
        \ch{106 CO2 + 122 H2O + 16 HNO3 + H3PO4 -> (CH2O)106 + (NH3)16(H3PO4) + 138 O2}\bigskip     
        
        \ch{"\color{blue}" 106}\ch{CO2 + 122 H2O + 16 HNO3 + H3PO4 -> (CH2O)106 + (NH3)16(H3PO4) + 138 O2}\bigskip
        
        \ch{106 \color{red}CO2 + 122 H2O + 16 HNO3 + H3PO4 -> (CH2O)106 + (NH3)16(H3PO4) + 138 O2}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an up to date `chemformula` you can set the option `stoich-format`. You can set it locally using `chemformula`'s `@{...}` syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \ch{
    @{stoich-format=\color{blue}} 106 CO2 + 122 H2O + 16 HNO3 + H3PO4
    ->
    (CH2O)106 + (NH3)16(H3PO4) + @{stoich-format=\color{blue}} 138 O2
  }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]